# UIImageView IBOutlet Properties for CollectionView Cells Not Loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableView and UICollectionView loading the same content, but, even though their protocol methods are defined almost identically, the collection view is giving me an empty view, whereas, the table view displays content. So that you understand the context of this question, I will cover what goes on before loading content on both views:

1. I get back an image from -imageWithData and store it in a dictionary
2. This dictionary is then accessed by the TableViewController class as well as the CollectionViewController class and implemented as such:

   ```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Configure the cell...
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"User ID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   //setting UI
   NSString *milesFrom = self.streamItems[indexPath.row][@"MilesAway"];
   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, Distance Away: %@", self.streamItems[indexPath.row][@"UserName"], milesFrom];
   UIImage *photo = [[UIImage alloc]init];
   photo = self.streamItems[indexPath.row][@"ThumbnailPhoto"];
   cell.imageView.image = photo;

   return cell;
   }
   ```

   This part works just as I need it to, but the collection view does not:

   ```
   - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       static NSString *identifier = @"MyCell";
       CellViewController *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

          UIImage *imageReturned = [[UIImage alloc]initWithCIImage: self.streamItems[indexPath.row][@"ThumbnailPhoto"]];
       cell.imageOfCell.image = imageReturned;
       [cell.imageOfCell sizeToFit];

   return cell;

   }
   ```

This CellViewController Class has the IBOutlet 'imageOfCell' property. This property references an Image View object that I dragged on top of the cell ("MyCell") that is  inside of my collection view. The collection view, as I said, gives me a blank view with no content. In debugging, I saw that both the 'photo' instance and 'ImageReturned' instance had the same exact values. For this reason, I have no idea why the collection view does not load the images but the table view does. In case it has anything to do with the way I load the collection view, I have included my -viewDidLoad method definition:

```
    @implementation StreamCollectionViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.collectionView.delegate = self;
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
        [self.collectionView registerClass: [CellViewController class]forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc]init];
        [flow setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical];
        [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flow];

        //create object to deal with network requests
      StreamController *networkRequester = [[StreamController alloc]init];
        [networkRequester getFeedWithCompletion:^(NSMutableArray *items, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        self.streamItems = items;
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    }

    else{
        NSLog(@"Error getting streamItems: %@", error);
    }
    }];

// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Register cell classes
       // [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I am fairly new to using the collection view so I wouldn't be surprised if it's something relatively small that I am missing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Two questions:\na) Are you using `- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{` to set up the number of cells?\nb) Have you tried `[UIImage imageNamed:self.streamImages[indexPath.row]]` instead of `[[UIImage alloc]initWithCIImage: self.streamItems[indexPath.row][@"ThumbnailPhoto"]];`?

Comment: @GlennRay Yes, -numberOfItemsInSection: returns [self.streamItems count]). I just tried using -imageNamed: like you said and got a runtime error: NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: [NSDictionaryM stringByDeletingPathExtension]: unrecognized selector sent to instance... ???

Comment: How about `[UIImage imageNamed:self.streamImages[indexPath.row][@"ThumbnailPhoto"]]`?

Comment: Yes, I assumed you had simply forgotten to add the [@"ThumbnailPhoto"] in your first comment, so I added it when I went to test it. Is there anything else that seems odd to you about my implementation?

Answer (score 0):

In  delegate of uicollectionView cellforrowatindexpath

After
        CellViewController *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

Add this
    if(cell == nil)
cell = [[CellViewController alloc]init];

Comment: I tried that but nothing changed; the view remains empty. Could this have something to do with the way I add the cell class. It works with the tableViewCell image property but not in my collectionView which has a custom IBOutlet imageView property created in the CellViewController class.

Comment: I have also tried adding an IBOutlet of type UILabel just to see whether the problem is in the images themselves or in how I reference the IBOutlet property 'imageOfCell.' I had no luck, so I'm guessing there's a problem in how I reference the cell's UIImageView outlet

Comment: Problem might the way you are accessing the image from dictionary, don't use initWithCIImage method, do it the same way you do in table view delegate. CIImage are Core images and I don't think that's what you are saving in that dictionary initially.

Comment: That's what I am doing. Like I said, I have tried using a UILabel and it didn't work, so the problem is probably in how I reference the IBOutlet

Comment: Do you have any idea as to how I could fix this issue, or do you know what the issue even is?